# Python cannot find module named / Import error from two level deep subdir

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I am a little bit confused regarding this one. I don't know why it doesn't find the rpSubmit py. This behaviour is not special to this single .py but a general issue. I am using python2.7 and even different python installations face the same issue.

This code is from the menu.py that causes the import error: Import error: no module named rpSubmit:

```
from scripts.rpSubmit import rpSubmit
```

Here is the folder structure and since all `__init__.py`'s needed exist, right?:

```
    Verzeichnis: Z:\ZMM\00_pipeline\pipeline\nuke\master


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----        17.03.2019     19:00            gizmos                                                                    
d----        18.03.2019     14:32            scripts                                                                   
d----        17.03.2019     19:00            ToolSets                                                                  
-a---        18.03.2019     14:35        656 init.py                                                                   
-a---        18.03.2019     14:32        740 menu.py                                                                                                                                                                                     


    Verzeichnis: Z:\ZMM\00_pipeline\pipeline\nuke\master\scripts


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
d----        18.03.2019     14:32            rpSubmit                                                                  
-a---        18.03.2019     14:32          0 __init__.py                                                                                                                         


    Verzeichnis: Z:\ZMM\00_pipeline\pipeline\nuke\master\scripts\rpSubmit


Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                      
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                      
-a---        10.03.2010     01:52       3620 rpSubmit.png                                                              
-a---        18.01.2018     16:15       7591 rpSubmit.py                                                               
-a---        18.03.2019     14:32          0 __init__.py                                                                                                                            
-a---        18.03.2019     14:32       5638 rpSubmit.pyc
```

EDIT: After I renamed the folder to script (without s) it worked again. I have no idea why. Lucky accident.

Comment: Does `from scripts import rpSumbit` work?

Comment: No, it returns with ImportError: cannot import name rpSubmit

Comment: Just to double check: Did you install the module? Do you try the imports while being in the master folder (on the shell)?

Comment: The line from scripts.rpSubmit import rpSubmit is inside the menu.py which is inside the master folder. There is nothing to install as it is just a .py I want to import. Maybe package would be a better word instead of module?

Comment: ok, I had similar errors and almost lost it trying to figure out what exactly is wrong with my importations, now I don't even bother, just use this boilerplate and you're all set 
Just copy past this code above all your importations :
`import os`
`current_dir =` `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))`
`parent_dir = os.path.dirname(current_dir)`
`sys.path.insert(0, parent_dir)`

Tell me if it fixes your problem

Comment: Nope, doesn't work returns NameError: name 'inspect' is not defined.

Comment: Where are you _running_ `menu.py` from? Is it the `master` directory? E.g., `python menu.py`? Or from somewhere else?

Comment: It gets automatically read when I start a programm called nuke. It looks for files called init.py and menu.py in the location of the env var NUKE_PATH.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting the program from a folder that is not 'master', Python is most likely not finding rpSubmit because it searches for the 'scripts' folder in this folder (where you started the program), instead of in the 'master' folder.

To remedy this, change the `from scripts.rpSubmit import rpSubmit` line in menu.py to:

```
import imp
rpSubmit = imp.load_source('rpSubmit', r'Z:\ZMM\00_pipeline\pipeline\nuke\master\scripts\rpSubmit\rpSubmit.py')
```

This way, you set up an absolute path to the right script.